# Texts show up when starting Terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

The text/code below shows up whenever I startup my terminal. This started happening after I checked a box in VSCode settings on "Send Keybindings To Shell" under the Terminal section. The texts still showed up even after I unchecked the box. I tried restarting both VScode, Terminal, my mac, and tried checking/unchecking that box in settings several times but the problem persists.

I am using MacOS (Big Sur V 11.5.2) and Zsh.

I have no idea how to pinpoint where the problem is coming from and how to solve it. I'd appreciate suggestions on what steps I can take to solve this.

**EDIT**:
It was tab completion info, `autoload -U compinit` and `compinit -i`, in `~/.zshrc` that was causing the issue. If I comment this out, texts stop showing up. But even if I keep this part, tab completion stopped working. I'd like to keep my tab completion. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**What my terminal screen looks like when I start it:**

[image]

**Full text:**

```
add-zsh-hook () {
    emulate -L zsh
    local -a hooktypes
    hooktypes=(chpwd precmd preexec periodic zshaddhistory zshexit zsh_directory_name) 
    local usage="Usage: add-zsh-hook hook function\nValid hooks are:\n  $hooktypes" 
    local opt
    local -a autoopts
    integer del list help
    while getopts "dDhLUzk" opt
    do
        case $opt in
            (d) del=1  ;;
            (D) del=2  ;;
            (h) help=1  ;;
            (L) list=1  ;;
            ([Uzk]) autoopts+=(-$opt)  ;;
            (*) return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
    if (( list ))
    then
        typeset -mp "(${1:-${(@j:|:)hooktypes}})_functions"
        return $?
    elif (( help || $# != 2 || ${hooktypes[(I)$1]} == 0 ))
    then
        print -u$(( 2 - help )) $usage
        return $(( 1 - help ))
    fi
    local hook="${1}_functions" 
    local fn="$2" 
    if (( del ))
    then
        if (( ${(P)+hook} ))
        then
            if (( del == 2 ))
            then
                set -A $hook ${(P)hook:#${~fn}}
            else
                set -A $hook ${(P)hook:#$fn}
            fi
            if (( ! ${(P)#hook} ))
            then
                unset $hook
            fi
        fi
    else
        if (( ${(P)+hook} ))
        then
            if (( ${${(P)hook}[(I)$fn]} == 0 ))
            then
                typeset -ga $hook
                set -A $hook ${(P)hook} $fn
            fi
        else
            typeset -ga $hook
            set -A $hook $fn
        fi
        autoload $autoopts -- $fn
    fi
}
compdump () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
compinit () {
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extendedglob
    typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1 
    typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name 
    while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 = -[dDiuC] ]]
    do
        case "$1" in
            (-d) _i_autodump=1 
                shift
                if [[ $# -gt 0 && "$1" != -[dfQC] ]]
                then
                    _i_dumpfile="$1" 
                    shift
                fi ;;
            (-D) _i_autodump=0 
                shift ;;
            (-i) _i_fail=ign 
                shift ;;
            (-u) _i_fail=use 
                shift ;;
            (-C) _i_check= 
                shift ;;
        esac
    done
    typeset -gHA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
    typeset -gHA _compautos
    typeset -gHA _lastcomp
    if [[ -n $_i_dumpfile ]]
    then
        typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="$_i_dumpfile" 
    else
        typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump" 
    fi
    typeset -gHa _comp_options
    _comp_options=(bareglobqual extendedglob glob multibyte multifuncdef nullglob rcexpandparam unset NO_allexport NO_aliases NO_cshnullglob NO_cshjunkiequotes NO_errexit NO_errreturn NO_globassign NO_globsubst NO_histsubstpattern NO_ignorebraces NO_ignoreclosebraces NO_kshglob NO_ksharrays NO_kshtypeset NO_markdirs NO_octalzeroes NO_posixbuiltins NO_posixidentifiers NO_shwordsplit NO_shglob NO_warnnestedvar NO_warncreateglobal) 
    typeset -gH _comp_setup='local -A _comp_caller_options;
             _comp_caller_options=(${(kv)options[@]});
             setopt localoptions localtraps localpatterns ${_comp_options[@]};
             local IFS=$'\'\ \\t\\r\\n\\0\'';
             builtin enable -p \| \~ \( \? \* \[ \< \^ \# 2>&-;
             exec </dev/null;
             trap - ZERR;
             local -a reply;
             local REPLY;
             local REPORTTIME;
             unset REPORTTIME' 
    typeset -ga compprefuncs comppostfuncs
    compprefuncs=() 
    comppostfuncs=() 
    : $funcstack
    compdef () {
        local opt autol type func delete eval new i ret=0 cmd svc 
        local -a match mbegin mend
        emulate -L zsh
        setopt extendedglob
        if (( ! $# ))
        then
            print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
            return 1
        fi
        while getopts "anpPkKde" opt
        do
            case "$opt" in
                (a) autol=yes  ;;
                (n) new=yes  ;;
                ([pPkK]) if [[ -n "$type" ]]
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: type already set to $type"
                        return 1
                    fi
                    if [[ "$opt" = p ]]
                    then
                        type=pattern 
                    elif [[ "$opt" = P ]]
                    then
                        type=postpattern 
                    elif [[ "$opt" = K ]]
                    then
                        type=widgetkey 
                    else
                        type=key 
                    fi ;;
                (d) delete=yes  ;;
                (e) eval=yes  ;;
            esac
        done
        shift OPTIND-1
        if (( ! $# ))
        then
            print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
            return 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "$delete" ]]
        then
            if [[ -z "$eval" ]] && [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
            then
                while (( $# ))
                do
                    if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                    then
                        cmd="${1%%\=*}" 
                        svc="${1#*\=}" 
                        func="$_comps[${_services[(r)$svc]:-$svc}]" 
                        [[ -n ${_services[$svc]} ]] && svc=${_services[$svc]} 
                        [[ -z "$func" ]] && func="${${_patcomps[(K)$svc][1]}:-${_postpatcomps[(K)$svc][1]}}" 
                        if [[ -n "$func" ]]
                        then
                            _comps[$cmd]="$func" 
                            _services[$cmd]="$svc" 
                        else
                            print -u2 "$0: unknown command or service: $svc"
                            ret=1 
                        fi
                    else
                        print -u2 "$0: invalid argument: $1"
                        ret=1 
                    fi
                    shift
                done
                return ret
            fi
            func="$1" 
            [[ -n "$autol" ]] && autoload -Uz "$func"
            shift
            case "$type" in
                (widgetkey) while [[ -n $1 ]]
                    do
                        if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
                        then
                            print -u2 "$0: compdef -K requires <widget> <comp-widget> <key>"
                            return 1
                        fi
                        [[ $1 = _* ]] || 1="_$1" 
                        [[ $2 = .* ]] || 2=".$2" 
                        [[ $2 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$1" "$2" "$func"
                        if [[ -n $new ]]
                        then
                            bindkey "$3" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                            [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] && bindkey "$3" "$1"
                        else
                            bindkey "$3" "$1"
                        fi
                        shift 3
                    done ;;
                (key) if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: missing keys"
                        return 1
                    fi
                    if [[ $1 = .* ]]
                    then
                        [[ $1 = .menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$func" "$1" "$func"
                    else
                        [[ $1 = menu-select ]] && zmodload -i zsh/complist
                        zle -C "$func" ".$1" "$func"
                    fi
                    shift
                    for i
                    do
                        if [[ -n $new ]]
                        then
                            bindkey "$i" | IFS=$' \t' read -A opt
                            [[ $opt[-1] = undefined-key ]] || continue
                        fi
                        bindkey "$i" "$func"
                    done ;;
                (*) while (( $# ))
                    do
                        if [[ "$1" = -N ]]
                        then
                            type=normal 
                        elif [[ "$1" = -p ]]
                        then
                            type=pattern 
                        elif [[ "$1" = -P ]]
                        then
                            type=postpattern 
                        else
                            case "$type" in
                                (pattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                    then
                                        _patcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func" 
                                    else
                                        _patcomps[$1]="$func" 
                                    fi ;;
                                (postpattern) if [[ $1 = (#b)(*)=(*) ]]
                                    then
                                        _postpatcomps[$match[1]]="=$match[2]=$func" 
                                    else
                                        _postpatcomps[$1]="$func" 
                                    fi ;;
                                (*) if [[ "$1" = *\=* ]]
                                    then
                                        cmd="${1%%\=*}" 
                                        svc=yes 
                                    else
                                        cmd="$1" 
                                        svc= 
                                    fi
                                    if [[ -z "$new" || -z "${_comps[$1]}" ]]
                                    then
                                        _comps[$cmd]="$func" 
                                        [[ -n "$svc" ]] && _services[$cmd]="${1#*\=}" 
                                    fi ;;
                            esac
                        fi
                        shift
                    done ;;
            esac
        else
            case "$type" in
                (pattern) unset "_patcomps[$^@]" ;;
                (postpattern) unset "_postpatcomps[$^@]" ;;
                (key) print -u2 "$0: cannot restore key bindings"
                    return 1 ;;
                (*) unset "_comps[$^@]" ;;
            esac
        fi
    }
    typeset _i_wdirs _i_wfiles
    _i_wdirs=() 
    _i_wfiles=() 
    autoload -Uz compaudit
    if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
    then
        typeset _i_q
        if ! eval compaudit
        then
            if [[ -n "$_i_q" ]]
            then
                if [[ "$_i_fail" = ask ]]
                then
                    if ! read -q "?zsh compinit: insecure $_i_q, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure $_i_q and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? "
                    then
                        print -u2 "$0: initialization aborted"
                        unfunction compinit compdef
                        unset _comp_dumpfile _comp_secure compprefuncs comppostfuncs _comps _patcomps _postpatcomps _compautos _lastcomp
                        return 1
                    fi
                    _i_wfiles=() 
                    _i_wdirs=() 
                else
                    (( $#_i_wfiles )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wfiles%.zwc})}") 
                    (( $#_i_wdirs )) && _i_files=("${(@)_i_files:#(${(j:|:)_i_wdirs%.zwc})/*}") 
                fi
            fi
            typeset -g _comp_secure=yes 
        fi
    fi
    autoload -Uz compdump compinstall
    _i_done='' 
    if [[ -f "$_comp_dumpfile" ]]
    then
        if [[ -n "$_i_check" ]]
        then
            IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < "$_comp_dumpfile"
            if [[ _i_autodump -eq 1 && $_i_line[2] -eq $#_i_files && $ZSH_VERSION = $_i_line[4] ]]
            then
                builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
                _i_done=yes 
            fi
        else
            builtin . "$_comp_dumpfile"
            _i_done=yes 
        fi
    fi
    if [[ -z "$_i_done" ]]
    then
        typeset -A _i_test
        for _i_dir in $fpath
        do
            [[ $_i_dir = . ]] && continue
            (( $_i_wdirs[(I)$_i_dir] )) && continue
            for _i_file in $_i_dir/^([^_]*|*~|*.zwc)(N)
            do
                _i_name="${_i_file:t}" 
                (( $+_i_test[$_i_name] + $_i_wfiles[(I)$_i_file] )) && continue
                _i_test[$_i_name]=yes 
                IFS=$' \t' read -rA _i_line < $_i_file
                _i_tag=$_i_line[1] 
                shift _i_line
                case $_i_tag in
                    (\#compdef) if [[ $_i_line[1] = -[pPkK](n|) ]]
                        then
                            compdef ${_i_line[1]}na "${_i_name}" "${(@)_i_line[2,-1]}"
                        else
                            compdef -na "${_i_name}" "${_i_line[@]}"
                        fi ;;
                    (\#autoload) autoload -Uz "$_i_line[@]" ${_i_name}
                        [[ "$_i_line" != \ # ]] && _compautos[${_i_name}]="$_i_line"  ;;
                esac
            done
        done
        if [[ $_i_autodump = 1 ]]
        then
            compdump
        fi
    fi
    for _i_line in complete-word delete-char-or-list expand-or-complete expand-or-complete-prefix list-choices menu-complete menu-expand-or-complete reverse-menu-complete
    do
        zle -C $_i_line .$_i_line _main_complete
    done
    zle -la menu-select && zle -C menu-select .menu-select _main_complete
    bindkey '^i' | IFS=$' \t' read -A _i_line
    if [[ ${_i_line[2]} = expand-or-complete ]] && zstyle -a ':completion:' completer _i_line && (( ${_i_line[(i)_expand]} <= ${#_i_line} ))
    then
        bindkey '^i' complete-word
    fi
    unfunction compinit compaudit
    autoload -Uz compinit compaudit
    return 0
}
compinstall () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
is-at-least () {
    emulate -L zsh
    local IFS=".-" min_cnt=0 ver_cnt=0 part min_ver version order 
    min_ver=(${=1}) 
    version=(${=2:-$ZSH_VERSION} 0) 
    while (( $min_cnt <= ${#min_ver} ))
    do
        while [[ "$part" != <-> ]]
        do
            (( ++ver_cnt > ${#version} )) && return 0
            if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = *[0-9][^0-9]* ]]
            then
                order=(${version[ver_cnt]} ${min_ver[ver_cnt]}) 
                if [[ ${version[ver_cnt]} = <->* ]]
                then
                    [[ $order != ${${(On)order}} ]] && return 1
                else
                    [[ $order != ${${(O)order}} ]] && return 1
                fi
                [[ $order[1] != $order[2] ]] && return 0
            fi
            part=${version[ver_cnt]##*[^0-9]} 
        done
        while true
        do
            (( ++min_cnt > ${#min_ver} )) && return 0
            [[ ${min_ver[min_cnt]} = <-> ]] && break
        done
        (( part > min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 0
        (( part < min_ver[min_cnt] )) && return 1
        part='' 
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Fix: Back up your `~/.zshrc` (for example, `mv ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.bak`). Then remove it using `rm ~/.zshrc`. Restart the terminal. This in princlpe should fix your issue.

Also, you can copy back the relevant `PATH` informations, etc from the backed up `.zshrc` if necessary.

Comment: It was tab completion info, `compinit -i` after `autoload -U compinit`, in `.zshrc` that was causing the problem. If I comment `compinit -i` out, texts stop showing up. But I'd like to keep my tab completion. Any suggestions on how to fix this?